# Typescript type for form submit event

Tags: typescript

Supposedly I should use **FormEvent** for the **submit** event type in a form.

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/

However that type does not recognise an array of values. It only recognises a single value (ie. **e.target.value** and not **e.target[0].value**).

What type should I use for the submit function in a form so I can iterate over my form values?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState} from "react";

export default function Test() {

    const [input1, setInput1] = useState<string>();
    const [input2, setInput2] = useState<string>();

    return (
        <div>
            {/*//TODO what should 'e' type be??*/}
            <form id="myform" onSubmit={(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(e.target && e.target.length ? e.target[0].value : "nothing here..")
            }}>
                <input type={"textfield"} id="1" value={input1}
                       onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input type={"textfield"} id="2" value={input2}
                       onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> what should 'e' type be??

What you have with `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` is fine - but you can also omit it entirely (which I'd recommend) - there's no need to annotate types that TS can infer automatically. Less code when not necessary often means fewer possibilities of typos, fewer puzzles to solve, and greater readability, when there isn't lots of boilerplate to distract from the core functionality.

> It only recognises a single value (ie. e.target.value and not e.target[0].value).

Which is expected - the `.target` is the element the event was dispatched to, which in this case is the form. It's not an array.

If you want the iterate over all values of the inputs, then either use separate states for them and then just log each state like you're doing currently (and make sure to give the states an initial string value, not an initial undefined value):

```
const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');
// ...
console.log(input1);
console.log(input2);
```

Or, if the number of inputs is dynamic, construct an array of strings for state instead.

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState(['']); // start with a single input

// to update the input at index i, like inside a map function in the returned JSX:
(e) => {
  setInputValues(
    inputValues.map((val, j) => j === i ? e.target.value : val)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Latest React the type seems it should be `e: SubmitEvent`

Answer (score 3):

I used this for normal submits.

```
import { SyntheticEvent } from 'react';

const _onSubmit = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {}
```

But when i want get the submitter i use this:

```
const _onSubmit = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement, SubmitEvent>) => {}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        id="myform"
        onSubmit={(e: React.FormEvent) => {
          e.preventDefault();
           
        }}
      ></form>
    </div>
  );
}
```